# Properties of Orthogonal Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A be an orthogonal n x n matrix.  Is $A^T$ necessarily orthogonal also?

I know that $Rank(A) = Rank(A^T)$ but it's not obvious to me why this would necessarily preserve length...

Any help much appreciated,
Mariogs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An orthogonal matrix satisfies $A^T = A^{-1}$. If you take the transpose of both sides you get $(A^T)^T = (A^{-1})^T = (A^T)^{-1}$ by properties of transpose and inverse, so $A^T$ is also orthogonal.

Answer (score 1):

A matrix is orthogonal if it's transpose is it's inverse, i.e. $A^T=A^{-1}$ which implies $$A^TA=AA^T=I$$ so $A^T$ is also orthogonal (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix)).